# Copy all sheets from a targeted workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I am getting run-time error '2147 and for the life of me I can't see what I am missing.

All I am trying to do is from my current workook open a selected workbook and copy in all sheets.

Thank you.

```
    Sub GetFile()

Dim fNameAndPath As Variant
Dim wb As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook
Dim Ws              As Worksheet

fNameAndPath = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Excel Files (*.XLS), *.XLS", Title:="Select File To Be Opened")
If fNameAndPath = False Then Exit Sub
Workbooks.Open Filename:=fNameAndPath

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set wb2 = Workbooks.Add(fNameAndPath)

For Each Ws In wb2.Worksheets
   Ws.Copy After:=wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets(1))
Next Ws

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: What line is the error occurring on?

Comment: On line  Ws.Copy After:=wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets(1))

Answer (score 0):

```
Public Sub this()
    Dim path As String, fileName As String
    Dim sheet As Worksheet, thisWB As Workbook, thatWB As Workbook
    Dim arr() As Variant
    Dim rowC As Long, colC As Long
    path = "C:\Users\dcoats\Desktop" & "\"
    fileName = Dir(path & "*.xl??")
    Set thisWB = ThisWorkbook
    Do While Len(fileName) > 0
        Set thatWB = Workbooks.Open(path & fileName, True, True)
            For Each sheet In thatWB.Sheets
                arr = sheet.UsedRange
                rowC = sheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
                colC = sheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count
                thisWB.Sheets.Add After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
                thisWB.ActiveSheet.Range(thisWB.ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1), thisWB.ActiveSheet.Cells(rowC, colC)).Value2 = arr
            Next sheet
        thatWB.Close False
        fileName = Dir()
    Loop
End Sub
```

This should work for you. Careful though it loops through all files in a directory (sorry I basically copied/pasted this from a script library i keep).

Comment: I get the same error after this line   thisWB.Sheets.Add After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)

Comment: Does the `Protect Workbook` enabled in `thisWb`?

Comment: @RyanH I ended up having to change it - apparently somethings were not correct.

Comment: It is sort of working,  It is copying sheets to my hidden personal macro book.  Also I have one sheet that has embed files in, it is not bringing them over.

Comment: Ah that is a whole new can of worms. This code only brings sheet contents. I would have to figure out how to move the other items as well. It might be a while before i get back to you - work and all